# override css with important

Tags: html, css

I want to override default Dropdown properties that belong to react semantic UI

Here is my dropdown:

```
<Dropdown 
    placeholder="User" 
    selection 
    compact 
    options={userOptions}
/>
```

The text in my dropdown has too much padding so in my CSS I removed it like so:

```
.default.text {
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I got rid of the padding from the Dropdown icon as well:

```
.dropdown.icon {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

However, as you can see this only worked when I used !important

Related questions:

```
How come the icon padding only works by using !important -- the text padding did not need !important

I hear using !important is bad practice. Should I avoid using it at all costs? How else do I override these properties / What are best practices?
```

Answer (score 0):

*How come the icon padding only works by using !important -- the text padding did not need !important*

It depends on how styles are defined inside react semantic UI, don't forget, that CSS is **Cascading** Style Sheets, so in some cases you need `!impotrant` to override styles, in other you're not. For example:

```css
p {
  color: red;
}

p.colored-1 {
  color: blue;
}

p.colored-1 {
  color: green;
}

p {
  color: red;
}

p.colored-2 {
  color: blue !important;
}

p.colored-2 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<p class="colored-1">COLOR</p>
<p class="colored-2">COLOR</p>
```

*I hear using !important is bad practice. Should I avoid using it at all costs? How else do I override these properties / What are best practices?*

Don't use `!important` if it's not really necessary, but if there is no other way to override styles - `!important` will help you.

Answer (score 0):

CSS properties have levels of power called `specificity`. The stronger specificity, the more it will override other weaker definitions. So, react is probably using strong specificity which override your definitions. Using `!important` gives a very strong specificity level which wins the ones react is using. Look in the dev took for the winning rule and give an equal or stronger specificity in your style sheet.

So for instance the rule that sets the padding is:

```
.ui.dropdown .menu>.item
```

you'll need to override that rule yourself in your style sheet, with the property of `padding: 0`.

That'll work because your rule will be loaded after the `Segment UI` rule, and thus override it.

Giving `!important` considered bad practice because it's very strong and very hard to override, if you will want to do so in the future. There are certain places it's okay to use `!important`, but this is not the case...